# Cannot find module 'jquery'

Tags: jquery, spfx

I am using this tutorial to try to load jquery into my SPF project.
http://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/basics/add-an-external-library

I followed strictly

tsd install jquery --save

Update the config.json in the config folder to load jQuery from CDN. Add an entry to the externals field:

```
"jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"
```

Import jQuery in your web part:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

However I keep getting this errors

```
Warning - tslint - src/webparts/helloWorld/HelloWorldWebPart.ts(12,13): error no-unused-variable: Unused import: '$'
Error - typescript - src/webparts/helloWorld/HelloWorldWebPart.ts(12,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jquery'.
Error - 'typescript' sub task errored after 3.97 s
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using npm to install the typings:

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

Source: [Add jQueryUI Accordion to your SharePoint client-side web part](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part)